# I have an automator script that runs a curl request, how can I retrieve and display the progress in the menu bar?

Tags: applescript, automator

On Automator, I created a service item that uploads a file by executing a BASH script that uses a cURL request. The Applescript code looks like:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set pathtofile to (the POSIX path of input as string)
    set pathoutput to (do shell script "/usr/local/bin/uploadFile " & quoted form of pathtofile)
    display notification pathoutput with title "File Uploaded" sound name "Frog"
end run
```

The issue is that the icon on the menubar will show 0% until the entire upload is done. For example:

[image]

this will run until it is done, even when the upload is 99% done. Is there a way to retrieve the curl output information and dynamically update it to show the right percentage? Thanks!

Comment: Not with that status item.  The Automator progress status item indicates the percentage of _individual actions_ in the workflow that have been completed, so the entire **Run AppleScript** action just counts as a single item.

Comment: I see, is there a way I can override what it is reporting? I wrote up code to extract the last line of a curl stream, but so far I only see the progress meter work inside ScriptEditor. It seems that even if declare `set progress total steps to 100
set progress description to "Uploading File..."
set progress additional description to "Progress"
set progress completed steps to 0
` none of these make it, an I am still left with the above.

Comment: AppleScript doesn't know the progress of shell scripts, so you would need to get the download content size and compare to the current download.  Since you are looking at putting up your own status item or progress bar, I would just skip using Automator.